# How do I get Firefox to not remember my credit card details?

Tags: privacy, firefox, autocomplete

I just realized that on a certain website I've purchased things from, the credit card details are being autocompleted.

Even the 3 digit key on the back of credit card is being autocompleted.

I like the remember my password feature and I like the autocomplete features too, so I don't want to get rid of them, but how do I make sure it doesn't my password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pre Firefox 4:
Tools > Options > Privacy > Saved forms > Settings > Clear Saved Form Data
Uncheck Save information I enter in forms

Firefox 4 check here:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Form%20autocomplete

Comment: Also keep in mind that some sites will store your information on their own servers in which case you're only recourse is to contact them and request that your info be purged. This may sound easy but occasionally it can be an absurdly difficult process.

Comment: Thanks, it'll be good if you can do it without clearing all of your saved form data. There should be a feature where you can say all fields that are "password" or credit card number or whatever should not be saved